# Why do i get this error every time i try to run the code within my U.I.?

Tags: netlogo

I have the code:

```
 if pcolor  = blue 
 [ask turtles-here [set heading towards one-of neighbors4 with [pcolor] = grey ] fd speed ].
```

This has the aim of making a turtle that is spawned on a blue patch set its heading towards a neighbour with pcolor = grey and then follow that path. However when I run the code I get the error :

WITH expected a true/false value from (patch -12 14), but got 55 instead.

I don't know what caused the error and what I should do to correct it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: in which context are you asking ? your `ask turtle-here` is in a patch context ?

Comment: in a patch context yes

Comment: it's not easy to help you with 2 line of code...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it come from a mise understanding of with condition ...

something like

```
 ask patches [
    if pcolor  = blue [
      ask turtles-here [
        set heading towards one-of patches with [pcolor = grey] 
        ] 
      ]
    ]
```

work for me !

Comment: Can be shortened to just  `ask turtles with [pcolor = blue] [ ... ]`

Comment: @SethTisue Nice ! I did not know!